# Cordova barcode scanner without show captured image

Tags: cordova

I want to know if there some way to use cordova barcode scanner plugin to scan without show captured image preview? Like a direct scan!

Comment: there is no option to hide image preview [read more](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner)

Comment: Well, how can explain.. when qrcode is scanned it take a picture, and show this picture for few miliseconds.. i want hide this picture and only scan.. is it possible?

Comment: Sorry, its not possible

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer :-D